# X Axis Sensor Correction - Flipped Sensor Detection - Froyo

Tags: android

We are trying to determine the best way to patch InputDevice.java to
correct a sensor issue. The touchscreen is detecting the location
opposite of the pressure. For instance, to unlock the device, I have
to put my finger in the exact spot on the left side of the screen for
it to register on the right side. The same thing happens for buttons,
press right to touch the left button, and vice versa. We thought it
might be possible to half the absolute value, but that may not work as
the absX range is 0-4095. From debug:

Left Side
D/InputDevice( 1062): reportData[j + MotionEvent.SAMPLE_X] = 3708.0
D/InputDevice( 1062): absX.minValue  = 0
D/InputDevice( 1062): absX.range  = 4095
D/InputDevice( 1062): w  = 799
D/InputDevice( 1062): reportData[j + MotionEvent.SAMPLE_X] = 3711.0
D/InputDevice( 1062): absX.minValue  = 0
D/InputDevice( 1062): absX.range  = 4095
D/InputDevice( 1062): w  = 799

Right Side
/InputDevice( 1062): reportData[j + MotionEvent.SAMPLE_X] = 256.0
D/InputDevice( 1062): absX.minValue  = 0
D/InputDevice( 1062): absX.range  = 4095
D/InputDevice( 1062): w  = 799

Would adjusting currentmove be the place? or is there a better way to
correct this issue in Froyo?

Answer (score 0):

if (absX != null) {

```
             reportData[j + MotionEvent.SAMPLE_X]=absX.range - reportData[j + MotionEvent.SAMPLE_X];





                reportData[j + MotionEvent.SAMPLE_X] =

                        ((reportData[j + MotionEvent.SAMPLE_X]-absX.minValue)   / absX.range) * w;

            }
```